# NSArrayController add: and edit

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary, nsarraycontroller

I have a simple tableview that displays file extensions which should be considered by my app. Now I want the user to be able to add/edit the entries in the table to add their own file extensions. I store the extensions in the preferences.plist (NSUserdefaults) in an Array that contains Dictionaries:

```
plist
   - Array (of fileExtensions)
        - Dictionary (aFileExtension)
            - String  (actual extension string e.g. @".zip")
```

Now, I have bound an arrayController to the Userdefaults and have the tableView bound to that arrayController. The extensions display fine. *happy face*

However, whenever I edit an entry, they highlight fine, I can edit the entry, click on a different one, all fine so far. When I close the window and open it again, the original values are restored, so apparently the arrayController does not persist the changes to the NSUserdefaults.

Do I need to tick an specific box in IB?

Answer (score 0):

Soooo, after some testing I found out that checking "Handles content as compound value" in the ArrayController in IB does the trick. Thought that might interest anybody looking up this thread.